# Parts of Australia that aren't dominated by white Australians that are easy for tourists to visit

Tags: australia, local-customs, remote-locations, indigenous-peoples

Basically, [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62159/parts-of-china-that-arent-dominated-by-han-chinese-that-are-easy-for-foreigners) but for Australia.

When I visited Alice Springs, while I was able to meet and exchange pleasantries a bit with Aborigines, virtually all of the staff I interacted with were white or Asian, except for a couple of the staff at the Alice Springs Desert Park.

Are there parts of Australia where a reasonable proportion of employees at ordinary shops, accommodation etc. are Aboriginal or Torres Strait Islander, are viable tourist destinations, and are legally open to outsiders?

Comment: The area around Nimbin comprises some 13 tribes, if my memory serves me well.

Comment: I find Australians dominate most tourist places around the world, let alone within Australia